# Python SQL SELECT syntax with multiple parameters LIMIT

Tags: python, pymysql

I have an SQL statement that works in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM kaio_jadwal WHERE param1=88 AND param2=973 AND param3=22554 LIMIT 0,10
```

When I try with Python:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM kaio_jadwal WHERE param1=%s AND param2=%s AND param3=%s LIMIT %s OFFSET %s"""
filter = (param1,param2,param3,limit,offset)
```

And I got an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''10' OFFSET '25''

And this is my code:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM kaio_jadwal WHERE param1=%s AND param2=%s AND param3=%s LIMIT %s OFFSET %s"""
filter = (param1,param2,param3,limit,offset)
cursor.execute(sql,filter)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

How should the syntax be in Python to work?

Answer (score 2):

`cursor.execute` is converting your limit and offset into strings, but MySQL expects ints. Try changing your SQL string with the `%d` notation for offset and limit:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM kaio_jadwal WHERE param1=%s AND param2=%s AND param3=%s LIMIT %d OFFSET %d"""
```

Comment: stil got eror  "%d format: a number is required, not str"

Comment: @Fatah check the type of limit and offset in your filter statement. It appears from the error that one or both of them are of type string not a number.

Comment: @Fatah as nagarwal said using %d implies converting the arguments to ints, so filter = (param1,param2,param3,int(limit),int(offset)) would solve